# How to change bibliographic style file (.bst) in case of entry with same authors

Tags: bibtex

I'm using BibTeX for editing my references in a dissertation with the `mcbride.bst` style.
According to the rules I have to write `---` when I have a reference entry with the same authors,
e.g.

> Author 1. 2011. Title....
>
> Author 2. 2011. Title 1....
>
> `---`. 2012. Title 2....

Now instead of `---`, I get a solid line.
I'd really appreciate any help in knowing what to change in the `mcbride.bst` file to get the described result.

Comment: Usually in TeX `---` *does* mean a solid line (an em dash, to be precise).

Comment: You could use something like `{-}{-}{-}` or `-\/-\/-` or `-{}-{}-` or even `-\null-\null-`.

Comment: Do the rules ask you to use `mcbride.bst`?

Comment: @egreg They just want me to use The Chicago Manual of Style

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [description](http://conway.rutgers.edu/~ccshan/wiki/McBride/) of `mcbride.bst`, *"[t]hree-em dashes are used in place of repeated author names"*. Here's the relevant function:

```
FUNCTION {name.or.dash}
{ 's :=
   oldname empty$
     { s 'oldname := s }
     { s oldname =
         { "---------" }
         { s 'oldname := s }
       if$
     }
   if$
}
```

If you *really* must use three separated em dashes, you could copy `mcbride.bst` to your working directory, rename it and then in the above function change `---------` to `---\/---\/---` or
`---\,---\,---`.

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer. It works, I used ---\,---\,---